# Is there a way to restrict Formik field to only accept letters and not accept numbers?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have fields like first name and last name and i want to make sure no number is passed in them. I am using formik. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [Yup Validation](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation) with Formik.
It's a really nice way of adding in tests either on the whole form with [validation schema](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#validationschema) or on [individual fields](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#validate-1).

You could make a test that matches for numbers with a Regex and the provide a validation error

Answer (score 1):

For that, you have to add a Validation method

```js
let text ='dfdfsd 1';
let pattern = /\d/g;
let result = text.match(pattern);
 if (result &&result.length) {
     console.log('Number are not allowed');
   }
```

Check this example I hope it will help you to understand the flow of how you can achieve your goal.